# Comparing Date type in Oracle PACKAGE does not work

Tags: java, sql, oracle, date, package

I made a Oracle Package like below.

And I will pass parameter String like '2014-11-05'.

```
--SEARCH 2014 11 04
FUNCTION SEARCHMYPAGE(v_created_after IN DATE, v_created_before IN DATE)
return CURSORTYPE is rtn_cursor CURSORTYPE; 
BEGIN
OPEN
rtn_cursor FOR
  select 
    news_id  
  from
    (
    select 
      news_id,
      news_title, news_desc,
      created, news_cd
    from
      news
    )
  where
  1=1
  AND (created BETWEEN decode(v_created_after, '', to_date('2000-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date(v_created_after, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
  AND (decode(v_created_before, '', sysdate, to_date(v_created_before, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) + 0.999999));
return rtn_cursor ;
END SEARCHMYPAGE;
```

I confirmed my parameter in Eclipse console Message, since I am working on Eclipse IDE.
I got contents, which are made in 2014-10-29 ~ 2014-10-31.

when I pass  '2014-11-01' as created_after, It returns 0 records.(But I expected all contents, since every contents are made between 10-29 and 10-31)

Would you find anything wrong with my Function?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create function search_my_page(p_created_after in date, p_created_before in date)
return cursortype
    is rtn_cursor cursortype; 
begin
    open rtn_cursor for
    select news_id  
    from news
    where created between
        nvl(v_created_after, date '1234-01-01')
        and
        nvl(v_created_before, sysdate) + interval '1' day - interval '1' second;

    return rtn_cursor;
end search_my_page;
/
```

Changes:

1. Re-wrote predicates - there was a misplaced parentheses changing the meaning.
2. Replaced to_date with date literals and variables.  Since you're already using ANSI date format, might as well use literals.  And date variables do not need to be cast to dates.
3. Replace DECODE with simpler NVL.
4. Removed extra parentheses.
5. Renamed v_ to p_.  It's typical to use p_ to mean "parameter" and v for "(local) variable".
6. Removed extra inline view.  Normally inline views are underused, in this case it doesn't seem to help much.
7. Removed unnecessary 1=1.
8. Replaced 0.99999 with date intervals, to make the math clearer.
9. Changed to lower case (this ain't COBOL), added underscores to function name.
10. Changed 2000-01-01 to 1234-01-01.  If you use a magic value it should look unusual - don't try to hide it.

Comment: Thanks for meaningful answer. My problem solved and I got extra tips :D b